# SessionRegistry does not have any principals

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to invalidate all sessions using Spring Security's SessionRegistry. Unfortunately, when I get the class, it does not have any principals. I have followed tutorial:
http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html
I have the following configuration:

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Needed by session information -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- UTF-8 Encoding -->
<!-- IMPORTANT! This filter must defined before all the others -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- PUT Support -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Error pages mapping - commented on developer server-->
<!--error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/errors/400.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/errors/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/pages/errors/500.jsp</location>
</error-page-->
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="agh.ideafactory.obieraki.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="shaPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="512"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder ref="shaPasswordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Session information configuration section -->

<!-- This is where session information is kept -->
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<!-- Concurrency filter used for concurrent session management -->
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/sessionexpired" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Login form beans - custom filters disables form-login tag -->

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/loginfailed" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Authentication filter used for handling login form -->

<beans:bean id="authenticationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Session Authentication Strategy - here we define parameters for handling session -->

<beans:bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- End of session information configuration section -->

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />

<http auto-config="false"
      use-expressions="true"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- We need custom filters to intercept session information -->
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />
    <!-- Unfortunately, it disables tag: form-login -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('STUDENT', 'YEAR_REPRESENTATIVE', 'ADMIN')" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    <!--<form-login authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
        <concurrency-control expired-url="/expiredsession"
                             max-sessions="1"
                             error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                             session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" />
    </session-management>-->
    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
</http>

</beans:beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<import resource="properties-configuration.xml"/>
<import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
<import resource="mvc-configuration.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:database/hibernate.xml"/>

<import resource="jsp-configuration.xml"/>


</beans>
```

And here I'm trying to invalidate user sessions:

```
[...]
public class SessionUtilsImpl implements SessionUtils{
[...]
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
[...]
@Override
public void invalidateStudentSessions( final Student student ) {
    final List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    for (final Object principal : principals) {
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            final User currentUser = (User) principal;
            if (currentUser.getUsername().equals( student.getUsername() )) {
                final List<SessionInformation> sessionInformations = sessionRegistry
                        .getAllSessions( currentUser, false );
                for (final SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionInformations) {
                    sessionInformation.expireNow();
                    sessionRegistry
                            .removeSessionInformation( sessionInformation.getSessionId() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[...]
```

No other methods here are using SessionRegistry.

So, what's happening? I have debugged class ConcurrentSessionStrategy and in there it works ok, but in my class I'm getting **another** instance of SessionRegistryImpl. Anyone has any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You are loading the same configuration twice. Both the `ContextLoaderListener` and your `DispatcherServlet` load the same configuration. Basically everything is duplicated. Spring Security uses the stuff from the `ContextLoaderLIstener` you ar using stuff from the `DispatcherServlet` and those aren't the same instances. Solution don't load the same thing twice.

Comment: Thanks, M.Deinum, for your help. I actually got this to work ;)

Comment: @MichałCiołczyk I'm having the same issue, how did you managed to get this to work?

Comment: @yin03 It was problem with loading the application context (and with it, Spring Security configuration) twice: once through ContextLoaderListener and once during the startup of DispatcherServlet. Make sure you are loading it only once and it'll be fine.

Comment: @MichałCiołczyk , thanks for the reply.  I'm still on the shadow though.  Can you expound on "loading it only once"?  To illustrate, my web.xml is very similar to what you have posted above, I have a listener tag for ContextLoaderListener and a servlet tag for DispatcherServlet.  What should I do to them to make it work?  Thanks for your assistance! :)

Comment: @yin03 Servlet automatically loads <name-of-the-servlet>-servlet.xml. So the file mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml is loaded twice in the code shown above. I have post the code after changes in contexts on gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ca05b08c9c823d50369e
You can see that we've moved loading everything regarding app context (including Spring Security) to ContextLoaderListener and everything regarding views to the servlet's context. So now there are still 2 contexts but Spring Security and other app beans are loaded once.